# How to properly build past perfect tense when something happened with an object?

Tags: past-perfect, sequence-of-tenses

I know that it should be *had* + verb in past form, but not sure about these sentences:

> This idea appeared when an apple had fallen on his head.

Meaning: first it felt, then an idea appeared at those moment when it felt.

Or

> This pencil appeared on the table when the other one had broken.

I suppose this would be wrong:

> This pencil appeared on the table when the other one became broken.

Meaning: one thing became broken and after than the other one appeared.

Comment: Not an answer, but I was thinking it could sound much better if you use active voice in all sentences, like _He got this idea_...

Comment: @Jan thanks, do you think those two are correct?

Comment: The pencil sentence sounds strange to me: How can a pencil just appear?

Comment: @Jan somebody put it there.

Comment: OK, no problem, I answered below with somewhat rewritten sentences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think that the two events occured at the same time in the past, you can use past simple twice:

> He got this idea *when* an apple fell on his head.

If you think that the idea was after apple, you can use past simple and past perfect:

> He got this idea *after* an apple had fallen on his head.

and the later also in:

> This pencil appeared on the table *after* the other one had broken.

To connect two clauses in the past simple, you use *when,* and to connect two clauses from which one is in the past and one before past (past simple and past perfect) you use *after* or *before.*

Source: https://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/pastperfect.html